# Soma da série 1+(2*3)+(4*5*6)+...+ n com implementação iterativa?

Tags: c++

Meu código:

Já tentei diversas vezes resolver esta questão, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que os valores não se repitam  e a variável soma multiplique os valores dentro de cada índice. Se alguém puder fazer e me explicar eu agradeço.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Dado um inteiro n, encontre a soma da série 1+(2*3)+(4*5*6)+...+ n.

int main()
{
  int i, n, t = 0, soma = 0, resp = 0;

  cout << "Entre com um valor n inteiro: ";
  cin >> n;

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    t += i;
    soma += (t*i);
  }

  resp = soma;
  cout << "A soma da sequencia e: " << soma;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se `n` for 8, o resultado deve ser 1+(2*3)+(4*5*6)+(7*8) ? Ou devemos calcular a soma de 8 termos (o primeiro é 1, o segundo é 2*3, o terceiro é 4*5*6, etc. até o oitavo, que é 29*30*31*32*33*34*35*36)?

Comment: Deve ser igual seu segundo exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não dá para fazer esse somatório de maneira direta como você está tentando fazer.

Para resolver esse problema tem um truque, você tem que criar uma função que calcule o primeiro termo só que ao invés dela retornar o resultado do termo ela deve retornar a soma desse primeiro termo com o próximo termo(usando a própria função de forma a criar uma cadeia que sempre buscará o próximo termo da série).

Para que o calculo não entre em laço você passa, para a função, um contador de quantos termos quer calcular assim como o número de termos a ser calculado:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 


// N = 1 --> 1                                 =     1
// N = 2 --> 1 + (2*3)                         =     7
// N = 3 --> 1 + (2*3) + (4*5*6)               =   127 
// N = 4 --> 1 + (2*3) + (4*5*6) + (7*8*9*10)  =  5167 

int somatorio(int valor, int termos_calculados, int termos)  
{ 
    int i, aux = 1; 
    //Se o número de termos caulculados passar o número de termos exigidos a função retorna 0 
    if (termos_calculados > termos) return 0; 

    //Calcula o term (a * b * c...)
    for (i = valor; i < valor + termos_calculados; i++) 
        aux *= i;  

    return aux + somatorio(i, termos_calculados + 1, termos);  
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int termos;
    cout << "Digite o número de termos na série:"<<endl;
    cin >> termos;  
    cout << "A soma da sequencia e: " << somatorio(1, 1, termos)<<endl;    
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu achei que este problema não é tão simples quanto parece, pelo menos para resolver de uma forma elegante. Além disso ele não está bem definido: o que acontece quando faltam parcelas no último termo do somatório ?

Abaixo uma solução simples para o problema. A chave é fazer uma iteração no número de parcelas, e então ir consumindo os números de 1 até o número que foi digitado.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// dado um inteiro n, encontre a soma da série 1+(2*3)+(4*5*6)+...+ n.

int main()
{
  int n;

  cout << "*\n";
  cout << "* digite uma valor inteiro: ";
  cin >> n;

  // regra de calculo: a cada iteracao i multiplicar os proximos i termos da sequencia
  // se nao houver numeros suficiente no ultimo termo, multiplicar os numeros que existem
  // este caso esta marcado com <-- na tabela abaixo
  // 0 --> 0                       =   0
  // 1 --> 1                       =   1
  // 2 --> 1 + 2                   =   3 <--
  // 3 --> 1 + (2*3)               =   7
  // 4 --> 1 + (2*3) + 4           =  11 <--
  // 5 --> 1 + (2*3) + (4*5)       =  27 <--
  // 6 --> 1 + (2*3) + (4*5*6)     = 127
  // 7 --> 1 + (2*3) + (4*5*6) + 7 = 134 <--

  int total = 0;
  int next_number = 1;

  for (int n_parcelas = 1; next_number <= n; n_parcelas++)
  {
    // valor inicial do termo, tem que ser 1 porque o termo é a multiplicacao de parcelas
    int termo = 1;

    // calcula proximo termo do somatório, com n_parcelas
    for (int i = 0; i < n_parcelas && next_number <= n; i++, next_number++)
    {
      cout << "* n_parcelas: " << n_parcelas << " / next_number: " << next_number;
      termo *= next_number;
      cout << " / termo: " << termo << " / total anterior: " << total << "\n";
    }

    total += termo;
    cout << "* total parcial: " << total << "\n";
  }

  cout << "* total: " << total << "\n";
  cout << "*\n";
}
```

Abaixo, testes com número de 0 a 5 (testei até 11, e estava certo).

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377046
*
* digite uma valor inteiro: 0
* total: 0
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377046
*
* digite uma valor inteiro: 1
* n_parcelas: 1 / next_number: 1 / termo: 1 / total anterior: 0
* total parcial: 1
* total: 1
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377046
*
* digite uma valor inteiro: 2
* n_parcelas: 1 / next_number: 1 / termo: 1 / total anterior: 0
* total parcial: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 2 / termo: 2 / total anterior: 1
* total parcial: 3
* total: 3
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377046
*
* digite uma valor inteiro: 3
* n_parcelas: 1 / next_number: 1 / termo: 1 / total anterior: 0
* total parcial: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 2 / termo: 2 / total anterior: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 3 / termo: 6 / total anterior: 1
* total parcial: 7
* total: 7
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377046
*
* digite uma valor inteiro: 4
* n_parcelas: 1 / next_number: 1 / termo: 1 / total anterior: 0
* total parcial: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 2 / termo: 2 / total anterior: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 3 / termo: 6 / total anterior: 1
* total parcial: 7
* n_parcelas: 3 / next_number: 4 / termo: 4 / total anterior: 7
* total parcial: 11
* total: 11
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377046
*
* digite uma valor inteiro: 5
* n_parcelas: 1 / next_number: 1 / termo: 1 / total anterior: 0
* total parcial: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 2 / termo: 2 / total anterior: 1
* n_parcelas: 2 / next_number: 3 / termo: 6 / total anterior: 1
* total parcial: 7
* n_parcelas: 3 / next_number: 4 / termo: 4 / total anterior: 7
* n_parcelas: 3 / next_number: 5 / termo: 20 / total anterior: 7
* total parcial: 27
* total: 27
*

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```

**ATUALIZACAO**

Uma outra solução, talvez mais fácil de entender.

```
// dado um inteiro n, encontre a soma da série 1+(2*3)+(4*5*6)+...+ n.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h> // abs

// ---

static int valor_digitado;

// ---

static int proximo_valor_a_processar()
{
  static int _proximo_valor_a_processar = 1;
  return
    (_proximo_valor_a_processar > valor_digitado) ? 0
      : _proximo_valor_a_processar++;
}

// ---

int main()
{
  cout << "*\n";
  cout << "* digite uma valor inteiro: ";
  cin >> valor_digitado;
  valor_digitado = abs(valor_digitado); // se digitar negativo transforma em positivo

  int total = 0;
  int valor_a_processar = proximo_valor_a_processar();

  for (int n_parcelas = 1; valor_a_processar; n_parcelas++)
  {
    int termo = 1;
    int n_parcela = 0;

    do {
      cout << "* n_parcelas: " << n_parcelas << " / valor_a_processar: " << valor_a_processar;
      termo *= valor_a_processar;
      cout << " / termo: " << termo << " / total anterior: " << total << "\n";
      valor_a_processar = proximo_valor_a_processar();
    }
    while (++n_parcela < n_parcelas && valor_a_processar);

    total += termo;
    cout << "* total parcial: " << total << "\n";
  } // for

  cout << "* total: " << total << "\n";
  cout << "*\n";
}
```